# How to get <input type=date> value in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm making a survey website and what I'm trying to do is get two dates from the user: start date and end date, and make the survey available between these days (I'll disable the take survey button after the end date). Before even getting to coding this logic, I can't take the user's input and display it in the console log. Here is what I have so far:

HTML:

`<input formControlName="startDate" id="startDate" type="date"/>`

TypeScript:

`const startDate = document.getElementById('startDate') as HTMLInputElement | null;`

`console.log(startDate?.value);`

And the console.log tells me it's undefined. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('change', () => {
  const startDate = document.getElementById('startDate')

  console.log(startDate.value);
})
```

```html
<input formControlName="startDate" id="startDate" type="date" />
```

Comment: I added a snippet to your question. `value` works fine

Comment: Yeah I tried that as well but I'm writing this in a TypeScript file and it gives me a red squiggly on document.querySelector() because 'Object is possibly 'null'.ts'

Comment: "*And the console.log tells me it's undefined.*" is drastically different from "'Object is possibly 'null'". In order to get help with a problem, it's vitally important to show the correct problem. Rather than another, unrelated problem that you do not even experience.

Comment: Just use `?.` instead of `.` after `document.querySelector('input')`.

Comment: I guess that you just run the code before user selects anything so it's an empty string `''`

Comment: @VLAZ I get what you are saying but if you read my question and comment carefully, you'll see that in my post, I had that problem, then I tried Konrad's code and it gave me a new error. So, I showed the correct problem.

Comment: you have formControlName why do you try to find it by id ? you should have form in your code. Can you please provide more code not just snipets

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to check whether the selected element is actually an input element before binding the callback function to its `change` event:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=9&ssc=38&pln=11&pc=56#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgSTABxFAogGwFMBbQsKRACgChFEA3AQ3xEIC5ECSyKAfRMCHz5E-cABNCwGGELiANNQCUHJi0LIUiABIAVALIAZDNjxFS5RAG9aiAE6EoIO0jWsA-ADoojAOYA5RlJEAF4wxAByNH8ABQBVXQiAbmoAX2pqCAQUChzGOygAEUYoQhMcUMRxOAgQCyhPX0cueoAhAE80cUoIvILi0oilFOoYYCpUcrNucko+opKyrBwlJWtbAHoNxDRxqAALDSywcRhYBERCN0WtKDhEKDtWRToth8OkA6O4YkwYIjsmkQEEIBUYMneJWQUF6iEYSAAPDJTAA+Ni2eYDJamTyMcTiXD0HiGVClWR2HoQfbwpoReRUNYhFHrOh0Y4oOBETz4OC+OY+fqLKaeNyEYa2VmSqXSmWILYAPXctlS4vShHwKA0Nle210h0u5h4lzOh0Bp3EYAiFEIAA9SZttnBAWdEAB3RgoS0UeGIJHLKAotJAA)

```ts
function isInputElement (
  value: Element | null | undefined,
): value is HTMLInputElement {
  return value?.tagName === 'INPUT';
}

const startDateInput = document.getElementById('startDate');

if (isInputElement(startDateInput)) {
  // If the condition evaluates to true,
  // then the compiler is certain that it's an <input>:
  startDateInput.addEventListener('change', () => {
    console.log(startDateInput.value);
                            //^? (property) HTMLInputElement.value: string
  });
}
else {
  // The element either didn't exist
  // or it wasn't an <input>
}
```

Compiled JS from the TS playground:

```js
"use strict";
function isInputElement(value) {
    return value?.tagName === 'INPUT';
}
const startDateInput = document.getElementById('startDate');
if (isInputElement(startDateInput)) {
    startDateInput.addEventListener('change', () => {
        console.log(startDateInput.value);
    });
}
else {
}
```

```html
<input formControlName="startDate" id="startDate" type="date" />
```

Comment: I appreciate your reply, I'll start doing more research and figuring the problem out (I didn't downvote you btw)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know why you are trying to use vanilla Javascript in an **Angular** project which uses **Typescript**, is not ideal, is not the `Angular` way.

Given your code example, you are using `ReactiveForms`, your input element has a `formControlName` which means, somewhere in the component's logic, you have the whole form created as a Javascript object, something like the following:

```js
...
  myForm!: FormGroup;  

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
       startDate: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }
```

If you simply want the value of the `startDate` control, then use the form object accessing the specific control, like this:

```js
getDate(): Date | undefined {
  return this.myForm.get('startDate')?.value; // it can be undefined
}
```

If you want to listen the input change everytime the user changes the value, then use `valueChanges` like the following:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.myForm.get('startDate').valueChanges.subscribe((theDate) => console.log(theDate));
}
```

Let's say you are not using `ReactiveForms`, and you want to select this input element, you could do it using a local reference onto the input element, and then access it in your code using `ViewChild`, like the following:

```html
<input type="text" #myName/>
```

```js
...
 @ViewChild('myName') myName!: ElementRef;

 getName(): string {
   return this.myName.nativeElement.value;
 }
```

I highly suggest you to read the official [docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/ReactiveFormsModule), if you don't know how to solve an specific scenario in an Angular project.

Comment: Thank you! I'll dive deep and figure it out, appreciate the reply.